# Finding an error in a partial integration

Tags: integration

There must be an error in this partial integration but I do not see it. Do you see it?

[image]

Comment: This is not a question about math education. It is a question about mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

The term in parentheses in the middle expression should be the change in $x\frac{1}{x}$ from $x = 1$ to $x = 2$ (which evaluates to zero), not just $x\frac{1}{x}$ (which evaluates to $1$).

But as @SueVanHattum says, we are here to defend mathematics education, not to practise it.

Comment: Although I wasn't seeing the error in this intriguing question, I had thought we probably shouldn't answer it, as it may be a graded exercise in a course.

Comment: @SueVanHattum Interesting point.  On other SE sites where I participate, the policy is that "homework questions" are considered on-topic only if the OP shows what efforts s/he has made to answer the question independently, and I thought OP in this case had met this condition (assuming that the original homework question was "compute the integral", not "find the error").

Comment: If the homework question had been "compute the integral", I wouldn't expect to see anyone use integration by parts. That's why I assumed it was "find the error".  (Thanks for giving me more info about the typical SE policy. On this site, we rarely deal with questions that could be homework, since they are math not math education, and I don't use other SE sites much.)

Comment: @SueVanHattum Why not? That particular integration-by-parts trick would work a treat if the integrand were $1/x^n$ with $n > 1$, so it's fairly natural to give it a try when the integrand is $1/x$.